# Compare element of string array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, compare

I have two arrays both having elements in string type.
Example :

**First Array**

```
$default_complaint = array("Login", "Printer", "Monitor", "Computer", 
                           "Network", "Other");
```

**Second Array**

```
$selected_complaint = explode(" ", $s['kindof_request']);
// Ex : it return like this => array ("Login", "Printer", "Monitor");
```

Now, how can I create the checkboxes that ticked in html by comparing that two arrays given above. So, I create like this:

```
<?php 
$default_complaint = array("Login", "Printer", "Monitor", "Computer", "Network", "Lain-lain");                      
$selected_complaint = explode(" ", $s['kindof_request']);

foreach ($default_complaint as $dc) {
    foreach ($selected_complaint as $sc) {

    $check = strcmp($dc, $sc) ;
    if ($check == 0) { //True
          echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">'. "$sc" ."<br />";
        } else{ //false
          echo '<input type="checkbox">'. "$dc"."<br />";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

My code still give me weird result. So, How to create like this, => (0) meaning checked.

```
(0)Login   (0)Printer   (0)Monitor   ()Computer   ()Network   ()Others
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two loops, but you only want to loop over the first array. The second one is only used for checking.

One possibility for the loop is:

```
foreach ($default_complaint as $dc) {

    if (array_search($dc, $selected_complaint) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">'. "$dc" ."<br />\n";
    } else{
        echo '<input type="checkbox">'. "$dc"."<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the help. but your code just ticked the last checkbox
()Login   ()Printer   (0)Monitor   ()Computer   ()Network   ()Others   ,
Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

(You don't have to do a nested foreach loop)

```
<?php

    $default_complaint = array("Login", "Printer", "Monitor", "Computer", "Network", "Lain-lain");                      
    $selected_complaint = explode(" ", $s['kindof_request']);

    foreach($default_complaint as $k => $v) {

        if(isset($selected_complaint[$k]) && in_array($selected_complaint[$k], $default_complaint))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" checked>' .  $v . "<br />";
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox">' . $v . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the help. but your code just ticked the last checkbox
()Login   ()Printer   (0)Monitor   ()Computer   ()Network   ()Others   ,
Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `foreach` loops. Only one will do it. Loop through `$default_complaint` array and check whether that element is present in `$selected_complaint` array using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Try using:

```
<?php
    $default_complaint = array("Login", "Printer", "Monitor", "Computer", "Network", "Other");
    $selected_complaint = explode(" ", $s['kindof_request']);

    foreach ($default_complaint as $dc)
    {
        if (in_array($dc, $selected_complaint))
            echo '<input type="checkbox" checked>' . $dc . '<br>';
        else
            echo '<input type="checkbox">' . $dc . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

You can also try [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) instead of `in_array()`.

Comment: Thanks 4 the help. but your code just ticked the last checkbox ()Login ()Printer (0)Monitor ()Computer ()Network ()Others , Thanks again...

Comment: @FadlyDzil I don't get any problem with this code. Please look [here](http://goo.gl/a9KAu3). Thanks.

Comment: Oke, I solved this problem with :
$selected_complaint = array_map('trim', explode(',', $d['kind_of_request']));

There is commas where explode